# How to Stream string data from a txt file into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, streamreader

---

I'm doing this exercise from a lab. the instructions are as follows

This method should read the product catalog from a text file called “catalog.txt” that you should
create alongside your project. Each product should be on a separate line.Use the instructions in the video to create the file and add it to your project, and to return an
array with the first 200 lines from the file (use the StreamReader class and a while loop to read
from the file). If the file has more than 200 lines, ignore them. If the file has less than 200 lines,
it’s OK if some of the array elements are empty (null).

I don't understand how to stream data into the string array any clarification would be greatly appreciated!!

```
    static string[] ReadCatalogFromFile()
    {
        //create instance of the catalog.txt
        StreamReader readCatalog = new StreamReader("catalog.txt");

        //store the information in this array
        string[] storeCatalog = new string[200];
        int i = 0;

       //test and store the array information
        while (storeCatalog != null)
        {

            //store each string in the elements of the array?
            storeCatalog[i] = readCatalog.ReadLine();
            i = i + 1;
            if (storeCatalog != null)
            {
                //test to see if its properly stored

                Console.WriteLine(storeCatalog[i]);
            }
        }
        readCatalog.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
        return storeCatalog;
    }
```

Comment: For starters you should use a for loop, but further than that there's not really more to it. Are you getting any exceptions or something?

Comment: the exception i get is: IndexOutOfRangeException. the additional information states that: the index was outside the bounds of the array

Comment: The Matthew Whited solution should work but that's no fun. If you want to make yours work properly, note the following.  storeCatalog will never be null, it is a string array object that you created. ReadLine will return null if there is no more data, work with that instead. To make sure your StreamReader is properly disposed even if your code blows up you should apply a try-finally block, starting immediately after the creation of your StreamReader and the Close() should be in the finally section. This is equivalent to Matthew's using statement.

Comment: Thank you martin! I realize I have a lot of work to do when it comes to arrays, the StreamReader Class, and even null but I want to thank you for helping me clarify the code itself. I will take a look into the try-finally block as well. thank again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static string[] ReadCatalogFromFile()
{
    var lines = new string[200];
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("catalog.txt"))
        for (var i = 0; i < 200 && !reader.EndOfStream; i++)
            lines[i] = reader.ReadLine();
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I acutally had an iterator example so you could just do this... `"catalog.txt".AsLines().Take(200).ToArray();` but that wouldn't have the null values if the source file contained less than 200 lines.  There should probably also be a `File.Exists(...)` check in there somewhere as `new StreamReader` will throw an exception if the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints:

```
int i = 0;
```

This needs to be outside your loop (now it is reset to 0 each time).

In your `while()` you should check the result of `readCatalog()` and/or the maximum number of lines to read (i.e. the size of your `array`)

Thus: if you reached the end of the file -> stop - or if your array is full -> stop.

Answer (score 0):

A for-loop is used when you know the exact number of iterations beforehand. So you can say it should iterate exactly 200 time so you won't cross the index boundaries. At the moment you just check that your array isn't null, which it will never be.

```
using(var readCatalog = new StreamReader("catalog.txt"))
{
  string[] storeCatalog = new string[200];

  for(int i = 0; i<200; i++)
  { 
    string temp = readCatalog.ReadLine();
    if(temp != null)
      storeCatalog[i] = temp;
    else 
      break;
  }

  return storeCatalog;
}
```

As soon as there are no more lines in the file, `temp` will be null and the loop will be stopped by the `break`.
I suggest you use your disposable resources (like any stream) in a `using` statement. After the operations in the braces, the resource will automatically get disposed.

Comment: Thank you Alex. I appreciate the clarification for this code block as well as how a using statement can be used in this situation. Thank you for your time.